# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '__doPostBack' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am dynamically adding some check boxes in a page using javascript. While i click on the submit button after checking a check box i am getting an error " 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '__doPostBack' is undefined". Please help.   My java script code is below

```
function SendEmailScheduleFn() {
        var Operation = "SendSchedule";
        var Length = "<%= countEmployee%>";
         var Data = "";
         for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++) {
             var check = "Checkbox" + i;
             if (document.getElementById(check).checked == true) {
                 Data += document.getElementById(check).name + ',';
             }
         }

         var pageId = '<%=Page.ClientID %>';
        __doPostBack(pageId,Data + "," + Operation);
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

The blog here solved it. 
[Yousef Jadallah's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/insure-that-dopostback-function-implemented-on-the-page)

Here is the brief explanation from the blog. Thanks, Yousef.

Note that the __doPostBack function and the two hidden fields, “__EVENTTARGET” and “__EVENTARGUMENT,” are automatically declared by adding ScriptManger or server controls that make postback except Buttons and Imagebuttons, Therefore if you have a form with Textboxes and buttons where you want to use  __doPostBack function  then “Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected” exception will occur.

How to solve the problem :

You just need to call `ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference` Method in the page load.

Comment: Mind to briefly explain the solution? Note that an external link may become offline without notice.

Comment: I did have WebControls on my form as suggested in other answers and still got the error. This answer fixed my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had resolved this issue for myself by adding a **form** which "runat="server"". hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

`__doPostBack()` should be automatically included by any ASP.NET WebControl that could cause a post back. You sound like you are calling it manually in some Javascript you wrote. If so, you will need to include a WebControl, to make sure that function in inserted onto the page

Answer (score -1):

Old Question, But it will help someone.

If you using ASP.net webforms, please use script manager withing form tag. it will solve your problem.

thanks.